# Absolute positioned child inside a parent which can be scrolled

Tags: css, position, overflow

I'm trying to create a side navigation bar that includes multiple links with tooltips that smoothly appear outside the side navigation bar when a user hovers over a link.

The issue arises because the side navigation bar contains several sections and has a vertical scroll bar. Due to the 'overflow-y: scroll' property, I'm unable to position the tooltip outside the sidebar.

How can I ensure the tooltip appears outside the sidebar despite the presence of a vertical scroll?

I've created a CodePen to demonstrate the desired result without the scroll: https://codepen.io/Hecalim/pen/VwRwLJa

But here is the HTML (multiplicate the li to have multiple links)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem .2rem 0 rgb(150 150 150);
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  // ADD THIS TO SEE THE PROBLEM
  //overflow-y: auto;
  // height: 150px;
}

ul {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: .4rem 0 .4rem .4rem;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  gap: .4rem;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-block: .4rem;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: .4rem;
    background: rgb(240 240 240);
    border-radius: 50vh 0 0 50vh;
    color: rgb(50 50 50);
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -20px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rgb(240 240 240);
      z-index: 2900;
    }
    &:after {
      top: initial;
      bottom: -20px;
      box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 rgb(240 240 240);
    }
    i {
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      aspect-ratio: 1/1;
      background: rgb(160 160 160);
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    span {
      max-width: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: margin .1s linear, max-width .1s linear;
    }
  }
  .tooltip {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    scale: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: .6rem 1.2rem;
    background: rgb(80 80 80);
    border-radius: .4rem;
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: transform .2s linear, opacity .1s linear;
  }
   :hover {
    .wrapper {
      background: hsl(210 100% 42%);
      color: white;
      &:before {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 hsl(210 100% 42%);
      }
      &:after {
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 hsl(210 100% 42%);
      }
      i {
        background: hsl(0 50% 95%);
      }
    }
    +.tooltip {
      transform: translate(2rem, -50%);
      scale: 1;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="wrapper">
            <i></i>
            <span>Section 1</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Section 1</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I hope this information provides enough context for your help.

I already had some issues with overflow hidden and position absolute child and I know I have to place the position relative to a higher parent in the DOM.

But here, the overflow of the whole section is needed so I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Frankly I think it's due to the `position: fixed` sidebar not having a width defined. I'm not sure `position: fixed` is the right way to go here. `position: sticky` might be a better option but it will depend on your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not all combinations of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are supported. In particular, `visible` (the default value) only works if it is set on both axes; as soon as you set one axis to something other than `visible`, the other axis will behave as `auto` (see the third bullet point [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)).

My thought would be to make your sidebar wide enough to accommodate both the menu and the tool tips. It would contain two columns, the left one would contain the menu, and the right one would contain the tooltips. The right column would in fact overlap the rest of the page.

Comment: Thank you ! I imagine something like that also but didn't make it yet. Will update my answer if this work.